# Hiding a div when textboxes are empty - backbone, javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to show/hide a div depending on the lenght of text boxes. I am using a backbone structure, so not sure where to place the code..

but here is my code;

```
<input type="text" id="txtUsername" placeholder="username"><br> <input
type="text" id="txtPassword" placeholder="password">

<div id="results">
  // text here
</div>
```

js

```
$('#chooseScan').addClass('hide');
        if ($('txtUsername').length > 0 && $('txtPassword').length > 0) {
            $('#results').removeClass('hide');
            $('#results').addClass('show');
        }
```

Comment: What’s your question? Is it that the code doesn’t work, or that you don’t know where to put it, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few errors in your code which i didn't see earlier.

1. Need to use # in front of the id.
2. Use $('#txtUsername').val().length   to get length.
3. Need to put jquery file reference.(Don't know whether you put it)
4. $('#chooseScan').addClass('hide');(Is it chooseScan or results?)

Below is the working code.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.hide { 
    visibility: hidden;
}
.show {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('#results').addClass('hide');
     $('#txtUsername').bind('input', function() { 

        if ($('#txtUsername').val().length > 0 && $('#txtPassword').val().length > 0) {
            $('#results').removeClass('hide');
            $('#results').addClass('show');
        }
} );

 });

</script>

</head>
<input type="text" id="txtUsername" placeholder="username"><br> 
<input type="text" id="txtPassword" placeholder="password">
<div  id="results">

  // text here</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can link `keyup` event to your textboxes like this:
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xC4fQ/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#txtUsername').bind('keyup', showHideDiv);
    $('#txtPassword').bind('keyup', showHideDiv);    
});


function showHideDiv(){
    if ($('#txtUsername').val().length > 0 && $('#txtPassword').val().length > 0) {
        $('#results').removeClass('hide');
        $('#results').addClass('show');
    }
    else {
        $('#results').removeClass('show');
        $('#results').addClass('hide');

    }   
}
```

Also, there are few problems with your code:

1. Use `$('#InputTagId')` to access them by ID
2. Use `$('#InputTagId').val().length` to get length of their values